# How to add prefix to all files of xcode project's static library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

If want to add prefix "Foo" to all the files of static library of xcode project is that possible? One way is that I refactor> rename them one by one. But I want to do them all in a single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Automator on Mac and then add your files back again to the project (deleting the broken old references).